# Do you have questions about "Fringe"? Do you want to ask them, as well as possibly get "Fringe" stuff?

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

As I'm sure regular members of the site noticed, we had an insane amount of traffic yesterday. [One question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe) got over 12K views in a day (now up to over 14K). It did lead me to check out which questions have been as popular. The next most popular questions seem to be about *[Doctor Who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/who-is-the-eye-patch-woman)* and another, surprisingly, about *[Fringe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-is-colonel-broyles-alive-again)*. There are only 4 *Fringe* questions on the site, and I think there could be a lot more. This site skews heavily towards older science fiction and fantasy ([Star Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) and [Star Trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)) and newer properties only have a fraction of the questions ([Harry Potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), [Doctor Who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who) and [Game of Thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones)). I think the site can grow exponentially in the direction of newer stuff.

***So what can you do to help?***

**If you already watch *Fringe*** (Fridays at 9/8c on Fox in the US!), ask any *Fringe*-related questions that new episodes inspire. Also consider posting general questions about older episodes. If you're asking it, you're probably not the only one having that question. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself… and if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself. When answering these questions, do everything you can to overkill it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, ultra-clear answer that is just as complete and clear as you can muster.

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to a show that is currently on the air and on the minds of sci-fi/fantasy enthusiasts not on the site currently. These questions will hopefully bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Science Fiction & Fantasy.SE continues to have great answers like we have had in the past, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come!

**A new episode airs tomorrow night (Friday, November 4th) in the US. Tune in and ask questions!**

---

**If you do not watch *Fringe* currently** and want to help, Stack Exchange will get you caught up. **We will be rewarding users with Fringe DVDs to enable them to populate our site with awesome *Fringe* questions**. The grant will work like this:

- To be eligible, answer this question with your username and which season of *Fringe* you would like to receive on DVD.
- We will then reward the 4 highest-rep users with the season of their choosing on DVD, so they can populate the site with awesome questions as first-time viewers.

**The grant closes on Monday, November 7th at 4:00 PM EST/21:00 UTC.**

Comment: Will you do the same for Doctor Who?

Comment: @DavRob60 Yeah, Brett's said he'll have a grant at the end of this month when S6 blu/dvds are released.

Comment: Excellent, we're making more Fringe fans!

Comment: And what about Season 5 of Doctor Who?

Comment: @DavRob60 Yes, I plan on doing things similar to what I did for Star Wars (question push and grant combo) for Harry Potter and Doctor Who, later this month.

Comment: @BrettWhite I just check [Amazon.ca](http://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_CA=%C5M%C5Z%D5%D1&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Fringe+&x=0&y=0#/ref=sr_nr_scat_917972_ln?rh=n%3A917972%2Ck%3AFringe&keywords=Fringe&ie=UTF8&qid=1320695672&scn=917972&h=f60916fe94c9ba798b395dc282eb8c9bae800e69) and strangely, the Season 2 is cheaper in blu-ray than in DVD! (also true for season 1). So, FYI, I own a blu-ray player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OghmaOsiris and DavRob60 will be our Fringeonauts, boldly exploring the wide world of "Fringe" and expanding the borders of our "Fringe" content. Hurrah!

Answer (score 3):

**OghmaOsiris**

I'd watch all the seasons, lol. I always meant to get into that show, but never have.

So I guess I'd be up for getting the first season.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to Fringe that you'd like.

Comment: Yeah, I can. I just started watching the show today. I'm on the 5th episode now.

Comment: Awesome :)  Let me know if you need anything or when you have something to post.

Answer (score 2):

### DavRob60

I never even heard of Fringe before, So Flowing [Keen's recommendation on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2345829#2345829), I will go for **Season 2**.

Comment: I'd be willing to switch with you, too if you wanted season 1.

Comment: Well, I'm in Canada, so it will be a custom hell. I nobody else apply for the grant, maybe we will get 2 seasons?

Comment: Lol. Well I hope he doesn't...leave us in the dark... Ba dum ching!

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to Fringe that you'd like.