# Who wants Harry Potter: The Complete Collection Years 1-7 or Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 2?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promotional-grant

This is more last-minute than I usually like to propose grants ([video editing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wqNOXFV-__w) has been taking up my time), but the release of **Harry Potter: The Complete Collection Years 1-7** (as well as **the Deathly Hallows II**) tomorrow gives us an opportunity to expand the site's fantasy and [Harry Potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) content.

So I propose:

- 3 users with the highest-rep at grant's end will receive a copy of **Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 2** on either Blu-Ray or DVD.
- 2 users with the highest-rep at grant's end will receive a copy of **Harry Potter: The Complete Collection Years 1-7** on Blu-Ray or DVD.
- The recipients will be encouraged to ask thoughtful questions about Harry Potter in general and/or the films in particular. These same users (as well as all of our users) are encouraged to be "on call" and ready to answer any related questions that pop up about Harry Potter. Blogging would also be encouraged.

**Note** that users who ask for Blu-Rays must have the capability to play Blu-Ray discs; Stack Exchange will not provide a Blu-Ray player.

Also **note** that priority will be given to users who have not previously received items for the **[Star Wars](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/766/is-a-promotional-grant-for-star-wars-the-complete-saga-on-blu-ray-wanted)**, **[Walking Dead](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/857/who-wants-walking-dead-stuff)** and **[Fringe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/do-you-have-questions-about-fringe-do-you-want-to-ask-them-as-well-as-possib)** grants. If you were involved in those grants, still apply, and if 5 high-rep, new winners don't appear, you will get the stuff. I just want to make sure that *more users get the chance to participate* and also *not bog you guys down with media to intake*.

Please answer below with your **username**, if you either want **Deathly Hallow part 2** or **the Complete Collection** (you cannot enter for both, duh), and if you **prefer Blu-Ray or DVD**.

The recipients will be chosen on **Tuesday, November 15th at 4:00 PM EST/21:00 UTC**.

Comment: These grant runs should also get a featured tag in order to flash it on the main side as well

Comment: Note: For those newer who might think they don't have a chance, there's still plenty of room to toss in your name. Most of those who have submitted have previously won something, leaving the possibilities wide open.

Comment: @BrettWhite Dr Who's coming out next week.  Time for a grant?

Comment: @Brett - not everyone checks meta regularly. It would be appreciated if things like this are announced via a system message on the main site. I am pretty certain i might have been a contender had I known about the grants \*sniff*

Comment: @DVK And you touch on the big problem we're discussing over on the "What Criteria Should There Be For Grants" question. I 100% agree that system messages should be used, but that's apparently a big no-no with Stack Exchange (if we have system messages for everything, then none of them are important; I see the logic). I am going to experiment with running house ads constantly, for every grant, and giving grants more than a week's lead time. But overall, checking Meta is the safest way to not miss out on grants.

Comment: @BrettWhite - Thanks. Now that I know about grants, will do so :) (of course, having missed the ones for my core strengths, it is a barn, horse and a door situation :)))

Comment: @DVK Oh don't worry, there'll be more HP and Star Wars grants in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The recipient of Deathly Hallows part 2 will be the only person who applied for it:

- PearsonartPhoto

The recipients of the Complete Collection will be the two first-timers:

- Jack B Nimble
- Tony Meyer

Hurrah! Please send me your mailing addresses, as well as the link to your country's Amazon or DVD/Blu-Ray provider. Send that info to brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com.

Answer (score 2):

Jack B Nimble, I would like the complete collection on DVD.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to HP that you'd like.

Comment: Yes, I watched through the movies and now I'm re-reading the books. I haven't yet decided what I might write about though.

Comment: awesome - let me know if you need anything or once you're done.  I'm doing it the other way around - finished re-reading and am now doing the movies.  If you want to do the 'overview' post that @Keen  suggested that's fine with me - I can do the other idea.

Answer (score 2):

Tony Meyer; complete collection on DVD.

I've just finished re-reading the books; I'd planned to watch the films concurrently, but have only got through *Philosopher's Stone* so far because they are oddly popular in NZ's equivalent of Netflix.  I've seen bits of the second film but none of the others.

Answer (score 1):

OghmaOsiris

I'd also like the complete collection on Blu Ray :D

Even though I've already participated in the Star Wars grant, I still wanna do this one because I'm a greedy little bastard.

Jk! Its only fair to have others have a chance to get free stuffs. But it would be cool to watch all the movies in a row, lol.

Answer (score 1):

PearsonartPhoto

I already have all of the previous, it would suffice for me to only get Part 2. Blu Ray is what I would want as well:-)

I previously won the Star Wars grant, so...

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to HP that you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff

I'd like the complete collection on DVD - I had the first one years back, but it was lost in a move.

Haven't seen the rest yet.

Answer (score 1):

fabikw

As there is still time and room. I want the Deathly Hallows part II DVD.