# What form could a Harry Potter (film) blog post take?

Tags: discussion, blog

[Thanks to StackExchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/919/who-wants-harry-potter-the-complete-collection-years-1-7-or-harry-potter-and-th/933#933), I'll be watching the eight Harry Potter films soon.  It'd be nice to get a blog post out of this, but I'm not really sure what to write about (and I'd like to have something in mind when watching them).

There are thousands of reviews of the films online already (most of the films are quite old, of course), even of the latest one.  By the time I get to Deathly Hallows Part II not only will there be thousands of reviews of the film, but most likely even of things like the DVD extras.

Does anyone have any suggestions about something interesting and vaguely original that I could write about?  (I've got one idea, that I'll post as an answer, but I'm not sold on it, and would welcome a better idea).

For background: I've only seen the first film (and bits of the second) before.  I've read (and just re-read) all the books (including *Beedle* but excluding *Quiddich* and *Fantastic Beasts*).  I'm not an expert on film, so something like focusing on cinematography wouldn't work well.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest doing an overview of the entire saga.  Take notes as you watch them all, then write a sort of review of the entire tale.  Most reviews were for each individual movie, so a discussion of the entire story would be different.  Especially if this is your first time watching, as things with are old hat to many fans will be fresh to your eyes.

Comment: Since I am also receiving the collection as a grant, that sounds like an excellent idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that this would work well, but it's my only idea so far...

After watching each of the eight films, I post a question on the site - something relating specifically to that part of the Harry Potter story, and ideally specifically about the film (rather than just the book), and something that requires an in-depth detailed answer, not just trivia.  After the waiting period, I add a bounty (I'm thinking 100 rep, maybe 150 if I come up with a question I really like - about 1k rep total) to the question.

Once the bounty period ends, I take the question & answers and do a blog post that covers the material (like the 'question of the week' posts that other sites have, and our occasional featured questions).

Comment: I like the bounty idea. Its a free way to do a contest or something.

Comment: Somewhat free ;)  I spent some non-zero amount of time accumulating that rep.  (But I've got plenty, so I'm happy to spread it around).